# Issue loading CSS and JavaScript files in Laravel

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm having a strange issue in my Laravel 5.2 app. Specifically with loading some CSS and JavaScript files. I have this in the folder `public/assets` so, I have something like this:

```
|--public
|----/assets
|-------/css
|------------/auth
|---------------login.css
|----------main.css
|-------/js
|---------email.js
|---------/modules
|------------faq.js
```

That is my directory, so I'm loading the CSS with:

```
    <link href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/main.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/auth/login.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

And the JavaScript files with:

```
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/email.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/modules/faq.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also I'm loading another files as well but I'm explaining the basic situation. So, the thing is that the load of `login.css` and `faq.js` are giving me 404 error but the other files are loaded correctly, I even checked open the files through the absolute paths and they're loaded fine, also I made chown to www-data of the public folder but nothing works, so I don't know why a 404 error is triggered. What else should I check?

In the console of the browser the links that are loaded are:
http://mydomain/assets/js/modules/faq.js
http://mydomain/assets/css/auth/login.css

But they give 404 error, and the other files doesn't

Answer (score 0):

1. first check those 404 files are in there definitely
2. check those files have readable permisstion

Comment: 1.- Yes, I made it opening that files in the browser using the absolute path:  `http://myServerIP/public/assets/css/myfile`. 2.- I made in the server `sudo chown -R www-data` with that, apache now is the owner and should be able to open them

Comment: @SrednyMCasanova, this path is not correct, you need remove public path.so it's nginx problem, nginx documnet root should have public included